# Matlab R2015b Radiobutton Selection by Code

Tags: matlab-gui

The following code creates 3 radiobuttons. The selection function makes sure the appropriate content is shown:

```
function myui
bg = uibuttongroup('Visible','off',...
                  'Position',[0 0 .2 1],...
                  'SelectionChangedFcn',@bselection);

% Create three radio buttons in the button group.
r1 = uicontrol(bg,'Style','radiobutton',...
                  'String','Option 1',...
                  'Position',[10 350 100 30],...
                  'HandleVisibility','off');

r2 = uicontrol(bg,'Style','radiobutton',...
                  'String','Option 2',...
                  'Position',[10 250 100 30],...
                  'HandleVisibility','off');

r3 = uicontrol(bg,'Style','radiobutton',...
                  'String','Option 3',...
                  'Position',[10 150 100 30],...
                  'HandleVisibility','off');

% Make the uibuttongroup visible after creating child objects. 
bg.Visible = 'on';

    function bselection(source,callbackdata)
       display(['Previous: ' callbackdata.OldValue.String]);
       display(['Current: ' callbackdata.NewValue.String]);
       display('------------------');
    end
end
```

I would like to change the selection AND content shown *per code* (no user is clicking). 
I can set the radiobutton selection per code as:

```
set(bg, 'SelectedObject', r2);
```

This draws the blue dot for the correct radiobutton (seems selected), however, the correct content is not shown.
I guess I need to call the 'SelectionChangedFcn' by hand, which I cannot as it demands on 'callbackdata', which is a 'matlab.ui.eventdata.SelectionChangedData' class with no documentation yet.

**Question:** Do I need to create the 'callbackdata' myself to call the SelectionChangedFcn 'from outside' when coding a radiobutton change, or is there another way?

**Question2**: I'd appricate a tiny hint on why/when 'HandleVisibility' is useful or not, the MatLab documentation is too cryptic for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, about question 2: If you set the property `HandleVisibility` to `off` on the radiobuttons, you won't have acces to the handles of its in the handle of the `uibuttongroup`.

As an example, with `HandleVisibility` to `off`:

```
bg.Children

ans = 

  0x0 empty GraphicsPlaceholder array.
```

And with `HandleVisibility` to `on`:

```
bg.Children

ans = 

  3x1 UIControl array:

  UIControl    (Option 3)
  UIControl    (Option 2)
  UIControl    (Option 1)
```

It depends of how you want to access to your radiobuttons.

About the programmatically call to Callback function, I propose you to code your own Callback function instead of using the `SelectionChangedFcn` (You will have in that case to set `HandleVisibility` to `on`).
This solution works for me:

```
function myui

    figure
    bg = uibuttongroup('Visible','off',...
                      'Position',[0 0 .2 1]);

    % Create three radio buttons in the button group.
    r1 = uicontrol(bg,'Style','radiobutton',...
                      'String','Option 1',...
                      'Position',[10 350 100 30],...
                      'HandleVisibility','on');

    r2 = uicontrol(bg,'Style','radiobutton',...
                      'String','Option 2',...
                      'Position',[10 250 100 30],...
                      'HandleVisibility','on');

    r3 = uicontrol(bg,'Style','radiobutton',...
                      'String','Option 3',...
                      'Position',[10 150 100 30],...
                      'HandleVisibility','on');

    % Make the uibuttongroup visible after creating child objects. 
    bg.Visible = 'on';

    % Use here your own way to switch the buttons, I use a simple vector as a counter
    CounterToSelect = [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3];
    for k=1:length(CounterToSelect);
        pause(1)
        previousChild = bg.SelectedObject;
        selectedChild = bg.Children(CounterToSelect(k));
        bg.SelectedObject = selectedChild;
        DisplayInfoChildren(previousChild, selectedChild);
    end

end

function DisplayInfoChildren(previousChild, selectedChild)
    display(['Previous: ' previousChild.String]);
    display(['Current: ' selectedChild.String]);
    display('------------------');
end
```